# How to use angular-timelinejs3 in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, timeline.js

[image]Sorry, as I mentioning this. I am new to angular 6. I have seen this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-timelinejs3?activeTab=readme, and when I try to do it in angular 6. I stuck in the middle as they said "Add dependency to timeline your angular module: ngTimeline" that means which one ?.

I installed angular-timelinejs3. Added css and javascript to index.html.When i put 
 directive:
 in app.component.html.And how can i import the ng-timeline js3  in angular.I got the error.Template parse error.can anyone please help me in this?

```
In Index.html

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Trial</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/timeline3/latest/css/timeline.css">
  <script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.knightlab.com/libs/timeline3/latest/js/timeline.js"></script>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>

  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
In app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
//import { NgTimelineModule } from 'ng-timeline';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

In app.component.html

<timeline  control="timeline" height="80vh" options="options"></timeline >
In app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//import  'ng-timeline';
//import 'angular-timelinejs3';


//import  * as timeline from 'ng-timeline';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi! Please include a [mcve].

Comment: @msanford  bro! is that enough.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that's must better. It's better to post the error as text instead of an image (google can find it that way and it's more readable).

Answer (score 1):

this Angular-timelinejs3 package only supports Angular JS. Support for Angular 2+ is missing. Please find the alternate timeline package which supports Angular 2+.